# Dovecot Corrupted record in index cache file

Tags: dovecot

Since today I get this errors in dovecot logs:

```
Jun 23 19:44:04 home dovecot: imap(s2)<3314><ngfv/yDi3vHAqAEB>: Error: Corrupted record in index cache file /home/s2/Maildir/.Trash/dovecot.index.cache: UID 456: Broken physical size in mailbox Trash: read(/home/s2/Maildir/.Trash/cur/1655992443.M410376P31691.home,S=2673,W=2728:2,S) failed: Cached message size smaller than expected (2673 < 8192, box=Trash, UID=456)
Jun 23 19:44:04 home dovecot: imap(s2)<3314><ngfv/yDi3vHAqAEB>: Error: Mailbox Trash: UID=456: read(/home/s2/Maildir/.Trash/cur/1655992443.M410376P31691.home,S=2673,W=2728:2,S) failed: Cached message size smaller than expected (2673 < 8192, box=Trash, UID=456)
Jun 23 19:44:04 home dovecot: imap(s2)<3314><ngfv/yDi3vHAqAEB>: FETCH failed: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2022-06-23 19:44:04] in=303 out=1816 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

I deleted

```
dovecot.index.log
dovecot.index
dovecot.index.cache
```

and restarted Dovecot, but the error persists.

Matter of fact, the file `/home/s2/Maildir/.Trash/dovecot.index.cache` does not even exist anymore and is not on disk, but dovecot says `Error: Corrupted record in index cache file /home/s2/Maildir/.Trash/dovecot.index.cache`.
How can it have a corrupt record in a file that does not exist?

I am lost. Any help?

```
$ dovecot --version
2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b)
```

Comment: No compression or encryption that I know of. Filsystem is clean, and the Mailbox file is there with content. Dovecot was stopped and restarted because after a while I even rebooted the server.

Comment: Is it the *exact* same error persists, or just the message, for varying files? Anything funny going on in the actual maildir (what is the actual size of the file Dovecot is failing to properly cache the size for? Any empty files, or two files only differing in the suffix after the last comma?). Is Dovecot the only software writing to that maildir? Is it on an ext4 (or otherwise standard & local) filesystem?

Comment: Do mention the version number, there have been multiple corruption bugfixes in recent years, not all of them have made it into common linux distributions yet.

Comment: If its really a bug with handling some edge case in the actual mailbox contents.. create a new box, and call `doveadm index -u user mailbox` on it for each message file you copy over, stopping at whichever message file it produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

it's quite simple to fix it:

- Stop postfix
- delete dovecot.* files in folders accounts
- Start postfix